# Connecting to Oracle via VBA

Tags: vba, oracle, connection, ado, ole

All,

I am trying to connect to an oracle database via the Cloud through VBA.  Below is my code.  When I debug print my VBA after the variable "strConOracle" is set, the variable prints as below

***strConOracle***
Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Dat`enter code here`a Source=coloplast-stg-rdb.cloud.modeln.com:4004:CPHSTG; User ID=jpathil;Password=Jean1121;

This seems ok since my database credentials that I connect with via SQL Dev are below

username: jpathil
Password: Jean1121
hostname: coloplast-stg-rdb.cloud.modeln.com
Port: 4004
Service Name: CPHSTG

What could be wrong with the code below?  It fails at the last line "oConOracle.Open strConOracle"

```
Sub QueryConstructOracle()
Dim QueryVar As String
Dim db As Database
Dim rs As Recordset
HOST$ = Sheets("Connection Setup").Range("Server")
DBNAME$ = Sheets("Connection Setup").Range("Database")
ORACLE_USER_NAME$ = Sheets("Connection Setup").Range("User")
ORACLE_PASSWORD$ = Sheets("Connection Setup").Range("Password")
ORACLE_PORT$ = Sheets("Connection Setup").Range("Port")
sourcedb = Sheets("Connection Setup").Range("DataSource")
Dim strConOracle As String
Dim oConOracle, oRsOracle
Dim strSQL As String
On Error GoTo errHandler

Application.Calculation = xlManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False


' Set connections
strConOracle = "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source=" & sourcedb & ":" & ORACLE_PORT$ & ":" & DBNAME$ & "; User ID=" & ORACLE_USER_NAME$ & ";Password=" & ORACLE_PASSWORD$ & ";"
Set oConOracle = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
oConOracle.Open strConOracle

End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, the Error message I get is RunTime Error '424' object required

Comment: In addition below are the Library References I have selected ... if that helps

Visual Basic for Applications
Microsof Excel 15.0 Object Library
OLE Automation
Microsoft Office 15.0 Object Library
Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library
Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects Recordset 6.0 Library
Microsoft DAO 3.6 Library

Comment: Don't you have to put the IP of the server into the code.  Something the following or you are pulling it from the spreadsheet?

Comment: ServerShare = "\\175.27.18.189\Divisions\Directional\Motors"

Comment: Set NetworkObject = CreateObject("WScript.Network")

Comment: NetworkObject.MapNetworkDrive "", ServerShare, False, UserName, Password

Comment: Did you install an Oracle Client?

Comment: @Wookies-Will-Code, the code in question is VBA, your comments are VBScript. They are different and not related to the problem.

Comment: What are the values for `DBNAME$` and `sourcedb`? Seems to be redundant and possibly wrong. Most likely `sourcedb & ":" & ORACLE_PORT$ & ":" & DBNAME$` result in wrong data source, see https://www.orafaq.com/wiki/EZCONNECT

Comment: Server Name: coloplast-stg-rdb.cloud.modeln.com
Database Name: CPHSTG
Oracle Port: 4004
Oracle User Name: jpathil
Oracle Password: Jean1121
Data Source: coloplast-stg-rdb.cloud.modeln.com
Thank you WernFried

Comment: I did actually install the oracle client 12.

Comment: What is most strange is that I can connect via SQL Dev.  In this case I have the parameters in a spreadsheet and I am feeding from the ranges into the variables.  Then I am putting the variables into the connection string

Comment: Either way, thank you for trying to help Wernfried

Comment: SQL Developer is Java based and uses JDBC driver - which does not require any further client installation. Did you install Oracle Instant Client? The Instant Client does not include the OLE DB providers, you have to download and install it separately from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/net-downloads-160392.html

Comment: Data Source should be `HOST$ & ":" & ORACLE_PORT$ & "/" & DBNAME$`

Comment: I that code not VBA? It is from an excel worksheet, piping to a database on server.